# Google Analytics: Which events led users to a final event

Tags: google-analytics

My users are given 2 events to interact with:

- **Event A** - *Category*: Leading_Events, *Action*: Event_A_Action
- **Event B** - *Category*: Leading_Events, *Action*: Event_B_Action

Either event above eventually leads them to a final event *:

- **Final Event** - *Category*: Final_Event, *Action*: Final_Event_Action

I want to create a report that shows which *Action* of Leading_Events led the users to Final_Event_Action. Can it be done? Thanks.

* (there may be some other events in between before reaching Final Event, but A B are what matters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result with two segments using sequences, i.e. user with event action A followed by event action Final, and the other with event action B followed by event action Final.